# Can you display digital content from iOS app to Roku (Similar to airplay)

Tags: ios, roku

I noticed that Chromecast has an [iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender), that seems to allow similar behaviour to airplay in a iOS app. Does Roku provide a similar ability? I can't seem to locate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. It's complicated.

Roku supports Miracast, so if your app or device has it, it can "project" to Roku. This is easily done from Windows 8+ (PC or phone/tablet) or Android.

Since you said iOS though, it does not support Miracast (which requires some low-level wifi things, can't be done purely by library). Nor is there video AirPlay outside Apple (ask Apple why). So i can't think of a way.

Roku supports [DIAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_and_Launch) though, that's how videos can be cast from mobile Netflix and YouTube to a Roku.

Comment: An overview of these various options is available in the [External Control Guide](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide) in the Roku SDK documentation.